# Windows does not detect any modems anymore[HSPA]

Tags: windows, drivers, modem

By an accident i uninstalled my Connect manager (ZTE). but when i re-install it the virtual CD drive is detected but it does not detect the drivers.
When i direct to the folder containing the relevant drivers(.sys files) still it doesnt detect.

Then i tried a modem of a different brand Huawei the same problem presists
As i understand it is not a device(brand) driver specific issue as it does not detect modem(dongles) of any brand. when i plugged in a different USB device(a pen drive) the driver is detected and it works perfectly.

Please help me with the issue
i have tried system restore but it doesnt work. 
I want a repair that works without re-installing windows

[Edit] Uninstalling drivers/ software and reinstalling doesnt  work.
 the issue does not deal with the registry

Comment: Unplug the modems/dongles, uninstall all software/drivers, restart, use [USB Oblivion](http://code.google.com/p/usboblivion/), restart once more and try any one dongle. Let us know if it worked.

Comment: Tried it didnt work.. I am sure that the issue does not deal with the registry as i have tried your method and system restore in an earlier instance

Comment: If you have now all the software installed as before you uninstalled it, you may be able to rollback to a system restore point in which everything worked correctly.

Comment: Tried it mate it didn't work

Comment: It has to work, unless : (1) should rollback further, or (2) hardware problem.

Comment: Problem is not with the driver , or the hardware for that matter as i have tried several brands of modems its a configuration file issue as i see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say that it is not driver or hardware, that leaves only Windows.
However, as you have not specified the modem's hardware connection, hardware still remains
a possibility (for USB it is easy enough to check if the socket works by using an external disk
or key).

For fixing Windows without a complete reinstallation, I can suggest :

- Windows Update including optional updates
- [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)
- Extensive virus scans by several well-known anti-virus products (just to be sure)
- (The method that worked for this problem) If all fails : [repair install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html),
  which only refreshes Windows and without doing a complete installation, so leaving intact all 
  installed applications
  (you need for that an installation DVD of the same service-pack level as your current installation).

Make sure you have complete backups before starting.

Comment: Well i am going to try your suggestions. what info do you require of the modem's hardware connection?. It is a ZTE MF110 usb modem. and all the other modems that i have tried are also usb modems

Comment: Have you checked that this usb socket works?

Comment: If system restore and even repair install didn't manage to get modems working on your computer, the only suggestion I have left is to format the disk using slow format and reinstall Windows and everything from scratch.

Comment: the repair install method worked thank you :)